# Increasing function non-continuous on points of sequence - construction

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

How to construct strictly increasing function $f$, non-continuous on points of countable sequence of numbers $a_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}} + \dfrac{1}{2^{n+1} (a_{n+1}-a_n)}(x-a_n),\;\;\;\; a_n < x < a_{n+1}, \;\;\;\;(n \in \mathbb{N}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence of points $a_n$ is non-decreasing, then a good answer is $f(a_0) = 0 $ and for all other $x$
$$f(x) = x + n\theta(x-a_n) - (n-1)\theta(x-a_{n-1})$$
Here $\theta(u)$ is the step function ($0$ for $u<0$ and $1$ for $u\geq 0$).

If the sequence is not non-decreasing, and can't be transformed into a non-decreasing sequence, the problem is harder.

Comment: Hi, I asked for strictly increasing sequence ($x < y => f(x) < f(x)$)

Comment: Sorry, my $n-2$ was a typo, it should be $n-1$  If the $a_n$ are non-decreasing, that $f(x)$ is monotone increasing, and is continuous everywhere except at each $a_i$, where it takes a jump of 1 between the left and the right limit.